# Predicting continuous variable from 3d coordinates

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, dimensions

I have a dataset containing independent variables as three different 3-D coordinates. For reference, the data is structured like this

Independent 1: (1,2,3) , (4,5,6)...
Independent 2: (7,8,9), (10,11,12)...
Independent 3: (13,14,15), (16,17,18)...

Dependent: 0.5, 0.6...

Does anyone have any suggestions for ML/Regression techniques to apply to this data? So far, I have tried creating new features off these coordinates (distances between the three x-y-z coordinates, area of the triangle in forms...). Nothing seems to give high accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on the context of what problem you're trying to solve. For example, in the context of a triangular mesh, additional interesting features might be the normal vector to the plane defined by the 3 points, and the distance of that plane to the origin. If this is some sort of geometry problem, you might care about the cross-products and dot-products between each pair of points.